# validating String.IsNullOrEmpty in C# with ternary operator

Tags: c#

the most of the time when I work with C# and need to validate a null or empty string I use the method:

```
 if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(s)) 
        return "is null or empty";
    else
```

but now I need to use this in this way:

```
string value= data.value==null?DBNull.Value:data.value;
```

I try to use both in the last sentence getting this

```
string value= String.IsNullOrEmpty(data.value)?DBNull.Value:data.value;
```

but always return true even is there is not any value in the property data.value, BTW data.value is a string, could you please tell me if my sentence is right or what seems to be the problem?

Comment: `IsNullOrWhitespace` may be?

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense. Your code seems to say "if value is null, then use null else use the value" which is redundant.

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh just a question, IsNullOrWhitespace generalizes the IsNullOrEmpty right? it is better to use IsNullOrWhitespace in my scenario since I don't know the value the property has

Comment: `string.Empty` is there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First off you cant use `string value = DBNull.Value` because those types are not compatible. You have to cast back to the common type which is `System.Object` so then the assignment becomes this which uses casting to ensure type compatibility:

```
object value = String.IsNullOrEmpty(data.value)
     ? (object) DBNull.Value
     : (object) data.value;
```

If you want to check for white space you can use [IsNullOrWhiteSpace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of `IsNullOrEmpty`

Comment: hello, the data.value property is a string and the field into which I want to save the value of the property (data.value) is a varchar and is defined in a SQL Anywhere Database, this database accepts NULL for null or empty strings, so my final questions is: do I have to use the object type this way: string value= String.IsNullOrEmpty(data.value)? (string) DBNull.Value : (string) data.value?  or do I have to use it with the (object) instead of string as you defined?

Comment: @PabloMayora - I am not sure what you are asking but based on your recent question history: `OleDbParameter.Value` is of type `System.Object`, if you want to pass `null` you have to pass `DBNull.Value` so assigning the instance `value` above in my answer to `OleDbParameter.Value` would be how to do that.